# PNG Chunk type-code Bit #5

Tags: python, png, file-format, bit

I'm trying to write my own little PNG reader in Python. There is something in the [documentation](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/png-1.2.pdf) I don't quite understand. In chapter 3.3 (where chunks are handled) it says:

> Four bits of the type code, namely bit 5 (value 32) of each byte, are used to convey chunk properties. This
>   choice means that a human can read off the assigned properties according to whether each letter of the type
>   code is uppercase (bit 5 is 0) or lowercase (bit 5 is 1). However, decoders should test the properties of an unknown
>   chunk by numerically testing the specified bits; testing whether a character is uppercase or lowercase
>   is inefficient, and even incorrect if a locale-specific case definition is used.

Ok, so it explicitly denotes one should **not** test whether a byte is uppercase or lowercase. Then, how do I check that *bit 5*?

Furthermore, the documentation states

> Ancillary bit: bit 5 of first byte
>   0 (uppercase) = critical, 1 (lowercase) = ancillary.

I have the following function to convert an integer to a bit-stream:

```
def bits(x, n):
    """ Convert an integer value *x* to a sequence of *n* bits as a string. """
    return ''.join(str([0, 1][x >> i & 1]) for i in xrange(n - 1, -1, -1))
```

Just for example, take the `sRGB` chunk. The lowercase `s` denotes the chunk is ancillary. But comparing the bit-streams of an uppercase `S` and lowercase `s`

```
01110011
01010011
```

we can see that bit #5 is zero in both cases.

I think I do have a wrong understanding of counting the bits. As the only bit that changes is the third one (i.e. indexed with 2), i assume this is the bit I'm searching for? It is also the 6th bit from the right and indexed with **5** (from the right of course). Is this what I'm searching for?

Comment: In case you find it useful, I've coded a PNG reader/writer (complete, expect for interlaced) in Java, and it's open source: http://code.google.com/p/pngj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does have bitwise manipulation. You are doing it the hard way, when they already gave you the bitmask (32 or 0x20).

```
is_critical = (type_code & 0x20) == 0
```

or, equivalently:

```
is_critical = (type_code & (0x1 << 5)) == 0
```

(with extra parentheses for clarity)

Comment: Ha right I didn't think about that xD Thanks. Btw isn't the hex of 32 `0x20`?